# Retrieve data from Google Drive file which is not shared by link in R

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-drive-api, r-googlesheets

I would like to import a file to R from Google Drive. I am trying this with `gsheet::gsheet2text`, but unable to retrieve information because it is not shared by link. How can I log in to get the data through R?

Comment: you might want to use `httr::GET` to download (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) the file

Comment: There's also the `googledrive` package: http://googledrive.tidyverse.org/